# Run Mathematica Processes on separate cores

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I need to perform several operations, each of which takes several hours to complete when run one at a time. Since I have 8 cores, I should be able to run them all at once instead of one after the other. However, I cannot find a way to instruct mathematica either to run them separately automatically or to run each on core X, with me manually setting where they go so they don't overlap. These are completely separate functions that just happen to need to run at once, not any type of group of similar operations such as seen in the documentation examples for parallelism (In this case, the function are a bunch of complicated unrelated symbolic integrals, but the answer will be of more general use if it is non-specific).

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what you are doing, but generally you can use a command like `Parallelize`, `ParallelTable`, `ParallelEvaluate` etc. In the `ParallelEvaluate` command, you have the option to specify the kernel.

You can compare in a very basic way these three:

```
Clear[a]
a[n_] := a[n] = RandomInteger[10^75]; (*Adjust exponent at your discretion*)
Timing[FactorInteger /@ Table[a[n], {n, 1, 4}]]
Timing[Parallelize[FactorInteger /@ Table[a[n], {n, 1, 4}]]]
%[[2]]==%%[[2]]
```

If you were to use `ParallelEvaluate`, you would be launching Kernels that function independently (which would make the above head-to-head comparison a bit trickier).

So, for your application, you might have something like this:

```
h[n_][x_] := Integrate[E^t*t^n, {t, 0, n x}]
Timing[Table[FullSimplify[h[n][x]], {n, 1, 10}]]
Timing[ParallelTable[FullSimplify[h[n][x]], {n, 1, 10}]]
```

Even in this simple example, you can see quite a speed-up.

Comment: For this case I merely have several integrals each of which takes an hour+ to do, and it would be nice to be able to run them all at once and get all the answers together instead of running them one at a time.

Comment: It sounds to me like a `ParallelTable` or similar will work just fine for you. If they are not indexed by an integer like the example, you could do this artificially by defining `h[n]:=Which[n==1,foo,n==2,foo...]` or using a similar trick to evaluate a table in parallel. Or you can just use `Parallelize` and write them all in a big long list manually like `Parallelize[{foo,foo,foo...}]`.